# Recursive Algorithm Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

I am having a difficult time figuring out where to start this problem.  Any input on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the recursive algorithm, which operates on a sequence of real numbers, S = {s0, s1, s2, ..., sn):

Function Questo(S)

First := the first element of s

If length(S) is 1

return First

End-if

S1 := S with the first element removed

return first + Questo(S1)

Let sequence T := (4,2,-1,3)

Which value is returned by Questo(T)?

Comment: Start with First:= the first element of T, which is 4.

Comment: Ok starting with 4.  Now length(S) is 1.  If 4 then not 1 it seems.  So 4 is removed.  But that return part confuses me because of no return first.  So return first is 0 + 4 = 4?  I am probably way off but I'm trying.

Comment: length(T) = 4, so skip the first If.  Now S1:=(2,-1,3).

Comment: Seems like the same thing happens with 2,-1, and 3 being removed.  So is it 0?

Comment: Yes, it is a recursive function.  Eventually you will hit length(S) = 1 when S=(3).

Comment: Ok so it's 3 because the length is 1.  So the answer is 3 then.

Comment: Yes, Questo(3) = 3.  Now work your way back up the stack to compute Questo(T).

Comment: So start back at 4?

Comment: No, compute Questo(3), then Questo(-1,3), then Questo(2,-1,3), then Questo(T).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\text{Questo}(T) 
&= \color{orange}{\text{Questo}(4,2,-1,3)} \\
&= 4 + \color{green}{\text{Questo}(2,-1,3)} \\
&= 4 + 2 + \color{blue}{\text{Questo}(-1,3)} \\
&= 4 + 2 + (-1) + \color{red}{\text{Questo}(3)} \\
&= 4 + 2 + (-1) + \color{red}{3} \\
&= 4 + 2 + \color{blue}{2} \\
&= 4 + \color{green}{4} \\
&= \color{orange}{8}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow so pretty much they are added together.  Why do they all leave Questo including 3?

Comment: For clarity, I added colors to the result of each Questo call.